# Parsing strings in vb.net and adding them to datatable

Tags: vb.net

I have a specific request in some application, I am given some text file which consists of some strings delimited by 2 delimiters.

Here is example of text file:

```
107,1,003090,1,Ok;param;param;param;param;param;
107,1,003090,2,Ok;param;param;param;
48,1,003090,3,Ok;param,param,param;
52,1,003090,4,Ok;param;param;param;
51,1,003090,5,Ok;
53,1,003090,6,Ok;param;param;
350,1,003090,7,Ok;param;
350,1,003090,8,Ok;param;
56,1,003090,9,Ok;param,param,param;
```

I am opening the file, adding the whole lines to some array like this:

```
    Dim returnCommands As New List(Of String)()
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(answerFile)
    For Each line As String In lines
        returnCommands.Add(line)
    Next
```

Next thing i would like to do is split the strings and add them to datatable which i have created before.

The thing is I do not know how to parse these strings because sometimes delimiter is comma and sometimes it is semicolon, this is how first line should be split:

```
107/1/003090/1/Ok/param/param/param/param/param/
```

Each value between "/" should be a value in my datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the eays way and `replace` the likes of the semi-colon with a comma then split then somehitng like this

```
newString = Replace(line, ";", ",")
newString.replace(",","/")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim returnCommands As New List(Of String())

Using f = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(answerFile)
    f.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    f.Delimiters = New String() {",", ";"}

    Do Until f.EndOfData
        returnCommands.Add(f.ReadFields())
    Loop
End Using

' You now a have a list of arrays of strings.
' Each list entry is a line, each array element is a field.
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` accepts multiple delimeters

```
Dim returnCommands As New List(Of String)()
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(answerFile)
Dim delimeters = New Char() { ","c, ";"c }

Dim lineValues = lines.
    Select(Function(line) line.Split(delimeters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).
    ToArray()

' Result
[
    ["107", "1", "003090", "1", "Ok", "param", "param", "param", "param", "param"],
    ... rest of lines
]
```

Comment: Looks like a C# answer to a vb question. Second time today. Actually, sort of a mix.

Comment: Actually, the vb editor in VS 2019 won't even let me put =>. It keeps changing it to >=. Argh! When I add code to an editor, I wish it would leave it alone!!